# SortedDict key: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, key, sorteddictionary

Please, help me to understand why setting `key` parameter of `SortedDict` in the following code:

```py
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
SortedDict({1:2, 0:1}) # works
SortedDict({1:2, 0:1}, key=lambda x: x) # TypeError
SortedDict({'a':2, 0:1}, key=lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x,str) else x) # TypeError
```

gives the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

How can one fix the examples?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

> The key-function argument must be provided as a positional argument and must come before all other arguments.

Your code should thus read:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
SortedDict({1:2, 0:1})
SortedDict(lambda x: x, {1:2, 0:1})
SortedDict(lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x,str) else x, {'a':2, 0:1})
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sortedcontainer` documentation says that you're calling the `SortedDict` constructor wrong:

http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

> The key-function argument must be provided as a positional argument and must come before all other arguments.